# Using selectors for droplists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selector, userscripts

I am able to use userscript to select a droplist with javascript if I know the ID of the droplist, but if the droplist doesn't have an ID I can't select it, so I'm wondering if there is a way to select all droplists that is on the page, without using the ID?

```
document.getElementById("id").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('select');
```

To select the first

```js
const first = document.querySelector('select');
console.log(first.selectedIndex);
```

---

**edit:**

Here you can see an example how too loop the multiple select-boxes and set the selectedIndex (in my case to 3)

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('select');

[...all].forEach(select => select.selectedIndex = 3);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

`all` is a NodeList and with `[...all]` or optional `Array.from(all)` you get an Array. This is needed to use the Array-Method `forEach`

Comment: Then which part of this actually selects the droplist? So do I have to change to to make it something like: document.querySelectorAll('select').selectedIndex = 0?

Comment: This is the part `document.querySelector('select')` and gives you the first selectbox. Here you can use `document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex = 0`

Comment: with the all selector `document.querySelectorAll('select')` you get a nodelist (array like). Here you have to convert the nodelist in an array and loop threw to set the selectedIndex(s)

Comment: Can you write an example loop for for how to do the "All" thingy?

Comment: added a small example. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.